# Problem with $_SESSION

Tags: php, iis, session

I have one webserver (IIS) and in this I have two folders: `website1` and `website2`, with two distinct copies of the same webapp. Once I login in one of them - say `mylocalip/website1` I start a session by quite standardly doing:

`$_SESSION["user_id"] = x;`

This works fine across my website. 
However, if I then go to `mylocalip/website2` I find myself still logged in. Quite strangely, if I go to `mypublicip/website2` I find myself not logged in.

My question is: why do I observer this behavior?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Session object is assigned to the domain name. You are using raw IPs here, so that becomes the domain name. Both folders are below the same domain name so they share the Session object.

However, when you go to the public IP address, the Session cookie for the other IP is not valid and so you need to login again.

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are retrieved by PHP by a coockie. The coockie is linked to an host or a sub folder of this host.

So, when changing folder on the same host, you keep this coockie, and you are still logged in. But when you connect yourself from your public IP address, you don't have the same host, so have a different session.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [session_set_cookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and set the `path` parameter to `/website1`.